# CKEditor demorando para carregar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugin, ckeditor

Estou utilizando a versão angularJS do CKEditor para gerar meus campos de texto. O problema é que ele apenas chama o plugin quando a página já está carregada. Por causa disso, ele espera todas as imagens que tem na página carregarem para só depois carregar o campo. Existe uma forma de eu agilizar o carregamento do plugin?